# ASPX link to ASPX with IFRAME(ASP page inside)... now I want to redirect back to ASPX

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have an ASPX page that redirects to a page that has an IFRAME which requests an ASP page on an entirely different domain. Once I'm done doing what I need to do there, I need to get back to the original ASPX page.

Is there anyway to do this? history.goback(-1) does not work as it just refreshes the IFRAME. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider includind a copy of the referer header as the HREF of an anchor in the outer page holding the IFrame.  Clicking this link would return to the referer.

This may not work in all circumstances.  Browsers can be configured to not provide a referer.

Comment: Adding a link outside the IFRAME won't work as the look of the page is supposed to be as if it was part of the application already. Basically, the IFRAME is serving up old pages we haven't converted yet to .NET. Preferably, I want a link inside the ASP page that would redirect.

Comment: This is what I eventually had to do due to not being able to access the window.parent because of the different domains.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the original URL as a querystring parameter to the ASP.

Comment: Since the ASP is being displayed in the IFrame this isn't that helpful.  I guess you meant the outer page that holds the IFrame for the ASP right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to consider some Javascript that can run from the page within the iFrame calling on the parent window to change the URL it has loaded.